# Python regex across multiline findall

Tags: python, regex

Am trying to parse through a document with the following layout. The aim is to find all lines with "Hong Kong Cases/Judgments/1946-1972" and "HIGH COURT".

My attempted code is as follows:

```
import re 
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1: name = "1946-1980,1982.txt"
handle = open(name)

for line in handle: 
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.findall("\bHong Kong Cases/Judgments/1946-1972.*HIGH COURT\b",line, re.DOTALL):
        print line
```

From my understanding the "re.DOTALL" should allow me to search through the multiple lines? However I end up with a none answer.

Any help on why this doesn't work would be much appreciated! Please forgive me if I've not set the question in the usual format, its my first time asking a question on stackoverflow. Thanks again!

==========================

```
Hong Kong Cases/Judgments/1946-1972 HKC/ATTORNEY GENERAL v CHAN WAH -
[1946-1972] HKC 684 - 20 April 1971


                                                                     8 pages



           ATTORNEY GENERAL v CHAN WAH - [1946-1972] HKC 684



HIGH COURT
```

==========================

Comment: [It works](https://ideone.com/2gTNTA) (=matches your string). What output did you expect?

Comment: what is `line` here.can you share how you are applying `re.findall`

Comment: Expected output is the exact image set out above. There are a large number of these in the document I'm trying to parse through. End goal is to count the number of times this pattern of text appears. 

However, when I try to print the above to check whether its returning me the right block of text it returns me nothing? Full code set out above after taking comments from vks. Thanks to all once again!

Answer (score 2):

```
re.findall("\bHong Kong Cases/Judgments/1946-1972.*HIGH COURT\b",line, re.DOTALL)
```

Remove `^` and add `\b` instead to get all matches.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fgOsys/1